# WPF FrameworkPropertyMetaData Journal -- What is the point of this?

Tags: wpf, metadata, dependency-properties, journal

Basically, just as the title asks:

What is the point of the Journal property? MSDN doesn't really explain it's actual usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nicely explained by this [blog post](http://laurenlavoie.com/avalon/167), or on the official [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#NavigationHistory).

To summarize though:

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   supports browser-style navigation that
>   can be used in two types of
>   applications: standalone applications
>   and XAML browser applications (XBAPs).
>   To package content for navigation, WPF
>   provides the Page class. You can
>   navigate from one Page to another
>   declaratively, by using a Hyperlink,
>   or programmatically, by using the
>   NavigationService. WPF uses the
>   journal to remember pages that have
>   been navigated from and to navigate
>   back to them.
>   ...
>   If you need to
>   remember small pieces of state across
>   Page navigations, you can use
>   dependency properties (see
>   DependencyProperty) that are
>   configured with the
>   FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Journal
>   metadata flag.

Comment: Would be nice if you could extract the key aspects so the answer does not loose its value if the link breaks or the blog disappears.